# Create table if not exists is costy?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I`m creating a simple data mapping system with PHP, PDO and Mysql.
One of its premises is to map arrays to entities by creating tertiary tables (not sure if the name is correct).

So, when I map an Array, I create the table with a works-for-all statement that uses the class name and method name passed, something like this:

```
"create table if not exists ".$tablename." (id_".$firstName." int unsigned not null, ".$secondName." ".$type.", constraint fk_".$tablename." foreign key (id_".$firstName.") references ".$firstName."(id) ".$secondReference.");"
```

The code is not the problem here.
What I wanted to know is if its a bad idea to TRY to create a table (if not exists) in every iteration (it does only create it for real in the first iteration of each element).

EDIT (explaining): As stated, creating inumerous tables is not the worry (wont happen), for this process is automated according to the classes (models) I`m using. The worry is if it is too costy memory and trafic-wise to check if the table exists at every iteration (this way for each item I would access the database twice, once for checking if the table exists and then again for inserting the new element into the table).

Another option would be to check if the table exists trough a select statement first, but it doesn`t seem much better.

One important information is that these methods used for mapping will olny be accessed through the objects DAO referencing each entity.

Edit: The link for the GitHub with the project is https://github.com/Sirsirious/SPDMap

Comment: Checking before execution always good

Comment: *'create a table (if not exists) for every array element"* why are you creating that many tables at all? sounds like a poor design

Comment: Dagon, it creates one table for each possible many-to-many table already designed in the model. It doesn`t create a table for each element, but it tries to create a table for the element name if its not created. I kind of want to worry only about modeling the classes, then let the system worry about the sql mapping.

Answer (score 0):

1. to me it doesn't sound ideal to create a table each time. Might be better to reuse the same table (with an additional column as identifier between your current 'tables'
2. if you do create the table, don't see anything wrong with `create table if not exist`. this is a safe and good programming
3. I'd also consider using temp tables for this thing. if you create the table each time, it sounds like they are one-time usage as well. so if you don't need the data forever, temp can be a good way to go

Comment: Read my new edit and see if you can understand better now.

Comment: @TiagoSirious - ok, I just read it. I still think this design is not optimal but you know the details better. in any case- if that's your design look at my #2 comment only. it will be for sure more efficient from network and memory point of view to use `create if not exist` rather than select before to check if it exists